# object reference not set to instance of an object nhibernate configuration buildsessionfactory

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

hiii i  am getting this error while running test for my fluent nhibernate application. not sure whats causing it .

here are my mappings and my domain

```
 public class Employee
{
    public virtual String emp_code { get; set; }
    public virtual String emp_name { get; set; }
    public virtual String expertise_id { get; set; }
    public virtual String grade_id { get; set; }
    public virtual String role_id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Status { get; set; }
    public virtual String email_id { get; set; }
}
```

this is my mapping

```
 public class EmployeeMap:ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("employee_master");
        Id(x => x.emp_code);
        Map(x => x.emp_name);
        Map(x => x.expertise_id);
        Map(x => x.grade_id);
        Map(x => x.role_id);
        Map(x => x.Status);
        Map(x => x.email_id);
    }
}
```

and my test class :

```
public class Test
{
    private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    [Test]
    public void Can_generate_schema()
    {

       sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(cfg).Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>()).BuildSessionFactory();

    }
}
```

can someone tell me why am i getting the error ??? what might cause it ?

Comment: How about posting the whole exception stack trace (http://vincnetas.tumblr.com/post/1130542373/stack-trace-or-gtfo)?

Comment: where is cfg being initialized in the code above?

Comment: @Cole okie sorry i got d error !! thanks :) it was my fault dint initialize the  cfg here

Comment: I posted this below.  Accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure cfg is initialized above.